# Nested If condition and logical AND operation

Tags: if-statement, logical-operators, cpu-cycles

```
void somefunction(struct *str, const char *status)
{
 if (str != NULL)
   {
      if (status != NULL)
      {
         str_copy(str->something, status, sizeof(str->something));
      }
   }
}
```

//which is better in the sense of CPU cycle above one or bellow one ?
Which takes more CPU cycle ?

```
void somefunction(struct *str, const char *status)
{
 if (str != NULL && status != NULL)
   {
         str_copy(str->something, status, sizeof(str->something));

   }
}
```

Which takes more CPU cycle ?

Comment: Why are random strangers on the internet going to be better at answering this than you just profiling both? Even if we did want to answer, you'd need to add more details such as what *language* this is (looks like C, but there again, so do a lot of languages)? What compiler? What processor?

Comment: With all modern compilers your code gets optimized. Also since the if (str != NULL && status != NULL) is evaluated from the left the code is identical. Also why would you care about optimizing this bit of code. I imagine the str_copy function takes 1000 times longer than the if statement.

Answer (score 1):

The second piece of code will be better if your language supports short circuit evaluation. In case of short circuit evaluation the second expression in the statement `if (str != NULL && status != NULL)` will not be evaluated if the first expression `str != NULL` evaluates to false. The advantage arises from the fact that your assembly code corresponding to the second piece of code will not contain the jump statement present in the assembly code of the first piece of code.

So this will give you slightly faster assembly code, unless the compiler performs some sort of optimization by itself. Profile both the codes to see whether your compiler is doing this or not.